# PowerShell: Method invocation failed because ... does not contain a method named

Tags: powershell

Working with OOP and PowerShell. I have a class defined with a bunch of methods, as can be seen when I run Get-Member against it:

[image]

```
Computer($c, $service){
    $this.Service = $service
    $this.Name = $c
}

[string] StartService() {
    Set-Service -InputObject $this.ServiceState -Status 'Running'
    $this.ServiceState.WaitForStatus('Running')
    return $this.ServiceState.Status
}

[string] EnableService() {
    Set-Service -InputObject $this.ServiceState -Status 'Manual'
    $this.ServiceState.WaitForStatus('Manual')
    return $this.ServiceState.Status
}

[string] StopService() {
    Set-Service -InputObject $this.ServiceState -Status 'Stopped'
    $this.ServiceState.WaitForStatus('Stopped')
    return $this.ServiceState.Status
}

[string] ServiceState() {
    $this.ServiceState = Get-Service -ComputerName $this.Name -Name $this.Service
    switch ($this.ServiceState.Status) {
        'Disabled' {
            if ($this.EnableService() -eq 'Manual')
            {
                if ($this.StartService() -eq 'Running')
                {
                    return $this.ServiceState.Status
                } else {
                    return "Unable to start the service"
                }
            } else {
                return "Unable to enable the service"
            }
        }
        'Stopped' {
                if ($this.StartService() -eq 'Running') {
                    return $this.ServiceState.Status
                } else {
                    return "Unable to start the service"
                }
        }       
        Default {
            return $this.ServiceState.Status
        }
    }
    return $this.ServiceState.Status
}
```

However, when I debug the script, it fails here:

```
Using Module "./Computer.psm1" 
Import-Module "./Computer.psm1" -Force
$service = 'RemoteRegistry'
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=OU HERE,OU=ANOTHER OU,OU=MORE OUs,DC=DOMAIN NAME,DC=com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$obj = @{}
foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    $CompObj = [Computer]::New($computer,$service)
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $CompObj.Name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ){
        if ($CompObj.ServiceState() -eq 'Running') 
        {
            $InstalledSoftwareKey="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
            $InstalledSoftware=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$computer)
            $RegistryKey=$InstalledSoftware.OpenSubKey($InstalledSoftwareKey) 
            $SubKeys=$RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames()
            Foreach ($key in $SubKeys){
                $thisKey=$InstalledSoftwareKey+"\\"+$key
                $thisSubKey=$InstalledSoftware.OpenSubKey($thisKey)
                if ($thisSubkey.GetValue("DisplayName") -like "Microsoft Office*")
                {
                    if ($obj.ContainsKey($thisSubkey.GetValue("DisplayName")))  {
                        $name = $thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName")
                        $obj.$name++
                    } else {
                        $obj.Add($thisSubkey.GetValue("DisplayName"), 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Write-Output "Unable to start the remote registry service on $computer"
        }
        if ($CompObj.ServiceState -eq 'Running') {
            $CompObj.StopService()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

What am I missing? I've re-opened Visual Studio Code, I have a using statement for the module file and when I import the module I'm using -Force. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code not in a screenshot?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: my understanding is that classes are _notoriously peculiar_ when imported via a module. you apparently need to do some "special things" to make it work ... and i cannot recall what that is at the moment. [*blush*] ///// have you tried to manually access and use the class in a script that ONLY imports the module and the tries to use that class?

Comment: Try `ServiceState()` instead of `ServiceState. If it is a method, you probably need the parenthesis at the end